# Get WordPress author link by ID

Tags: profiles

Is there any way to open an author's profile url using ID, like this;

Get WordPress author link by ID

`http://example.com/about/152/`

instead of default url:

`http://example.com/about/User-Name/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution this one, but you maybe be able to use it.
If you add ?author=X (x = id), the URL fetches the Author profile based on the ID.

Example: https://example.com/?author=152

Comment: ouh, i wanted that, yes!